# mismatch new[] and delete, why is there no memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, delete-operator

When combining `new[]` with `delete` instead of `delete[]`, what really happens?  I tried the following code and found there is no memory leak, so why does `delete` on a `new[]` returned pointer not cause a leak?

How does the compiler know the number of bytes to be freed?

```
int main() {
  constexpr int size = 102400;
  while (1) {
    char* buffer = new char[size]{};
    delete buffer;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not talking about valgrind here, I wonder if you delete a new[] pointer, how can it figure out the block size to be freed?

Comment: Now you have a good question. But extend that a step further: How does it figure out That your allocated array was one element or one million elements?

Comment: The code is not required to work without the `[]`, but it is also not required **not** to work.

Answer (score 4):

Formally the program behaviour is *undefined*, since you need to match a `new[]` with a `delete[]`.

But one possible manifestation of the undefined behaviour is for a compiler to "play nice", and do what you intended. (One of the compilers I work with does this and forms part of its documentation.)

But **don't** rely on that else you're not writing strictly portable C++.

Note also that you may well not *observe* a memory leak since the C++ runtime library and the operating system might not actually give you the memory until you make use of it. A compiler may even optimise out your loop entirely - as it's a no-op - especially if the memory allocation and deallocation calls were correctly written.

Comment: Talking about gcc here, how does it know the actual amount of size to be freed if call delete instead of delete[]?

Comment: @bugsking the actual byte size may be stored in a header at the front of the allocated memory. But it is still undefined behavior. And you could get leaks if you create an array of a class type that has a destructor. `delete` would not call all of the array element destructors, whereas `delete[]` would.

Answer (score 0):

If optimization is turned on, then compiler can remove your while-loop or inside allocation and deallocation of memory. Otherwise as was said, your program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: it's compiled in O0, no optimization.